# How to use concat in a for loop without using append?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have the following code that uses a for loop to iteratively create dataframes and append them to one large dataframe. It works, but I get this warning: "FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead."

```
district_list = [
   {'url':'blabla.com', 'name':'Montgomery County Board of Education', 'state':'MD'},
    {'url':'blabla.org', 'name':'Cabarrus County Schools', 'state':'NC'},
    {'url':'blabla.k12.us', 'name':'Mariposa County Unified', 'state':'CA'}]

districts_df = pd.DataFrame()

for district in district_list:

    url = district['url']
    district_name = district['name']
    state = district['state']
    
    df = pd.DataFrame([{'url': url,
                       'district_name': district_name,
                       'state': state}])
    
    districts_df = districts_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)

districts_df
```

I redid my code so that it uses concat. However, the code still uses append. I don't understand -- what is the point of switching to concat, and making my code more complicated, when I still have to use append anyway? Why am I no longer getting an error? Is there another way I should do this that doesn't use append at all?

```
districts_df = []

for district in district_list:

    url = district['url']
    district_name = district['name']
    state = district['state']
    
    df = pd.DataFrame([{'url': url,
                       'district_name': district_name,
                       'state': state}])
    
    districts_df.append(df)

districts_df = pd.concat(districts_df)

districts_df
```

Comment: Why are you not just using `pd.DataFrame(district_list)`? For concat, replace the line in your original code using append to: `districts_df = pd.concat([districts_df,df])`

Comment: In your second example, `districts_df` is initially a misnomer (untill you call `pd.concat`); it's really just a list so you are calling `list.append` within the loop which is a perfectly fine, non-depricated, method

Comment: Not_speshal's suggestion worked, thank you. The real code is much more complicated than this and I'm doing more than just grabbing the URL, name and state so that's why I didn't just use pd.DataFrame(district_list).